# Calculating multi variable integral over curve

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

> Calculate: $\int_\gamma e^{{x}^{2}-{y}^{2}}(\cos (2xy) \ dx+\sin (2xy) \ dy)$ where $\gamma$ is the unit circle with positive direction.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By letting $x=\cos(t)$ and $y=\sin(t)$ with $t\in [0,2\pi]$, the given integral becomes
$$\int_\gamma e^{{x}^{2}-{y}^{2}}(\cos (2xy) \ dx+\sin (2xy) \ dy)=I_1+I_2$$
where
$$I_1=\int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{\cos(2t)}(\cos(\sin(2t))(-\sin(t))dt$$
and
$$I_2=\int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{\cos(2t)}\sin(\sin(2t))\cos(t))dt.$$
Now 
\begin{align*}
I_1&=\int_{0}^{\pi}e^{\cos(2t)}(\cos(\sin(2t))(-\sin(t))dt\\
&\quad+\int_{0}^{\pi}e^{\cos(2(t+\pi))}(\cos(\sin(2(t+\pi)))(-\sin(t+\pi))dt\\
&=-\int_{0}^{\pi}e^{\cos(2t)}(\cos(\sin(2t))\sin(t)dt+
\int_{0}^{\pi}e^{\cos(2t)}(\cos(\sin(2t))\sin(t)dt=0.
\end{align*}
A similar argument holds for $I_2$. Hence $I_1+I_2=0$.

Comment: if i ran into an trig integral like that in calc class id quit